# Styling table column groups

Tags: html, css

I need have a table of related data. Some of the columns are grouped however. The designer has come up with a design which cannot be changed. An example is:

[image]

Each group of columns needs to be styled as the image shows. The data is all dynamic, so some tables may have 2 column groups, as above, some may have 6. Because the data is related, it should be in a table. But I think there is no possible way to style it to have the above effect when using 1 table. Heres my attempt in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2y66Lmh/).

```
<div>    
    <table cellspacing="0" >
            <colgroup span="3" >
            </colgroup>    

            <colgroup span="2" >
            </colgroup>  
        <thead>
            <th>
                col 1
            </th>    

            <th>
                col 2
            </th>  

            <th>
                col 3
            </th>   

            <th>
                col 4
            </th>      

            <th>
                col 5
            </th>      
        </thead>  

        <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td>item</td>
                   <td>item</td>
                   <td>item</td>
                   <td>item</td>
                   <td>item</td>
               </tr>    
        </tbody>    

    </table>    
</div>
```

And css:

```
 div{
      background-color: grey;
      display:inline-block;
      padding: 50px;
  }

  table{
      background-color: transparent;
      cellspacing: 0;
      border-collapse:collapse;
  }

  colgroup {
      background-color:white;
      border-right: 25px solid grey;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  }
```

As you can see, border-radius and box-shadow do not work.

What would be best way to represent this type of data? Is it possible to do in 1 table? Or do i need to do multiple tables? Or could I just use lots of `divs` (as previous developer has done)?

Comment: Can you add more information like data or how it should represent.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: No. You can't do that with tables. CSS styling on colgroups and cols is limited.